# Android : setPageMarginDrawable repeated y

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to have something like a notebook spiral between two viepager fragments. 
Therefore I use setPageMarginDrawable(impage_of_one_spiral) and setPageMargin(int_width_of_the_image);
The problem is, that it scales the image up. But I need to have it repeated in y direction. Is this somehow possible?
Thanks, Tata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get any good answer. So i created a new image out of my original image, copied it several times in y direction so it is probably bigger than every display. but i dont like this approach too much.